# Openvpn and routing for outside

Tags: networking, security, routing, openvpn, router

I installed openvpn on my router. Everything works great. But, when the tunnel is up, my router is no longer accessible from the outside (I have a "white" dedicated address). Packets get to the external interface and the response goes into the tunnel through the routing - this is clear. But how to deal with it?

I can’t show the server configuration (this is ProtonVPN), I can show the client configuration - it’s standard

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

remote X.X.X.X 80
server-poll-timeout 20

remote-random
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

# The following setting is only needed for old OpenVPN clients compatibility. New clients
# automatically negotiate the optimal cipher.
cipher AES-256-CBC

auth SHA512
verb 3

setenv CLIENT_CERT 0
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun

reneg-sec 0

remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
pull
fast-io

block-outside-dns

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFozCCA4ugAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0FADBAMQswCQYDVQQGEwJDSDEV
...............................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
6acef03f62675b4b1bbd03e53b187727
.........
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything turned out to be easier. (Who reads the documentation?) You just need to not accept the default gateway from the server:

pull-filter ignore "route-gateway"